# XeLaTeX download

Tags: xetex

I want to download XeLaTex. Searched and tried sites shown by google such as Texts.io, SourceForge, SIL, Pconlife but not able to download. Any authentic source, please advise.

Comment: You can download TeX Live or MiKTeX.

Comment: Perhaps [texlive](https://tug.org/texlive/) is what you look for.

Comment: You don't download xelatex as it does notthing on its own, you need a LaTeX installation

Answer (score 4):

Downloading XeLaTeX only does not make any sense. XeLaTeX is XeTeX engine + LaTeX format. But to use it, you would need several more parts of a *TeX distribution*, e.g., LaTeX classes, LaTeX packages, Fonts etc. So to download XeLaTeX, you should download (and install) a complete TeX distribution. Currently there are mainly two TeX distributions:

- [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive)
  A multi-platform TeX distribution available for several CPU architectures and OSes. It evolved decades ago from the most common TeX implementation for Unix/Linux at the time. The installation is described on the homepage. Linux users can often find corresponding packages in the package manager of their Linux distribution. Within the Linux package manager it can indeed happen that XeTeX and XeLaTeX are contained in their own packages. The package search may help to find the corresponding package. For Debian/Ubuntu, for example, the Linux package `texlive-xetex` must be installed, for SuSE Linux package `xetex` would be needed.
- [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org)
  Meanwhile, this is also a multi-platform TeX distribution. Until a few years ago it was a Windows-only TeX distribution. It is still mainly used by Windows users. The installation is described on the homepage. In contrast to TeX Live, MiKTeX's usual practice is to install only a base at first and have all other required parts installed automatically as needed. An online connection is then required for this automatic post-installation. To my knowledge, no Linux distribution offers MiKTeX via the package manager.

For users it could seem that there is a third *distribution*, which I have not in the list above:

- [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex)
  is a package which installs TeX Live on the Apple Macintosh (see above).

So to get XeLaTeX install one of these TeX distributions. If you install TeX Live with the Linux package manager, also have a look for packages with name part `xetex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: MacTeX isn't 'mainly' TeX Live. It *is* TeX Live for Macs. The fact that it includes some OS X specifics doesn't make it an adaption/derivative as 'mainly' suggests, any more than the inclusion of Windows-specific bits makes the Windows version of TL anything but TL. (The Windows version also includes an editor, as well as `perl` and defaults differ e.g. support for GUI installation is included and this is the default, which is not the case on Linux.)

Comment: @cfr As a non-native speaker who doesn't really feel at home in English, I'm sure I'll always be subject to such hair-splitting. Therefore I have now copied the shortest description from the MacTeX homepage. This should hopefully satisfy everyone.

Comment: But it isn't a third distribution .... Otherwise, you should list several more distributions: the fourth (TeX Live for Linux, say), the fifth (TeX Live for Windows), the sixth (TeX Live for BSD) etc. MacTeX is just TeX Live (for Macs), just as there is TeX Live for other platforms, such as Windows and Linux. This isn't hair-splitting and it isn't about how it is phrased. It's about presenting it as a different distribution, when it isn't. It has a separate name because it used to be distributed separately (before TeX Live). But that's just a name.

Comment: @cfr As you said: “It is distributed separately.” From the user's point of view, it therefore makes sense to mention it separately as well, in my opinion.

Comment: I did NOT say that. I said it *used* to be distributed separately. In the past. I don't think TeX Live even existed. It is NOT distributed separately now. It is available from the TeX Live page in just the same way as those for Windows and vanilla Linux. The versions produced by Linux distros *are* distributed separately, so there's a case for separating those (which you don't do). MacTeX is distributed as TeX Live by TeX Live. It *was* a different distribution years ago. It is certainly not a different distribution now.

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that Linux distros make their own decisions. Some of them cripple `tlmgr`, for example. Some omit documentation. Debian omit parts which don't meet their licence criteria. Even rolling distros don't give you the same version you get if you use TeX Live's own installer. It would make much, much more sense to treat those separately.